# Taking CSV data as source for Dataflow task in Azure DataFactory I'm getting invalid records/data and tried to filter out those records but no luck

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have data in Blob storage CSV format, and need to apply some transformations for that using DataFlow activity in azure data factory, so now while taking CSV data as source for Dataflow task I'm getting extra records due to invalid data format so data breaks in middle and moved to next line for suppose col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
1451645,Apple,Univer
se,78569,04/07/2023   this was the format, and only few records getting error

Any suggestions/answers on this please

I tried to replace space between them, but not worked
how to fix this out

Comment: Hi,Can i have the sample dataset so that i can understand and try it out on my side .

Comment: sample DATA g_user_id u_user_title u_first_name u_mid_name u_last_name u_email_address u_logon_name u_user_security_password b_change_password u_password_question u_password_answer u_account_status dt_date_created g_user_id_changed_by dt_date_last_changed dt_date_registered 

 

1222736 MIS        rah  Pat eWebQA@gmail.com sps146 hC/G7QU/p/w== FALSE What's my code?  FALSE     

\ \"dl11xe\"" 1 17:16.7 857283559 14:42.0    FALSE   FALSE